# Changing a set of buttons to a menu

Tags: java, android, layout, android-menu

So I have 3 different buttons on my layout. Now as I was creating my layout for phones etc. I decided that having 3 buttons on that page was a waste of space. Those buttons already have a ton of code logic behind them, to set their visibility, replace strings depending on situation etc.

My question is, is there a simple way to change them to a menu, is it possible to simply copy the layout XML I had for them on the main page, and paste it inside a menu?

That menu would open from a simple button, and then present all 3 buttons inside of the menu. So they aren't taking up space the entire time. Will this break the code I already have? Imagine I have the following code. Will it still

```
            bLogin.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Exit));
bLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

And so on. I'm concerned with the menus behavior, will it close when I click one of the options, will the visibility attributes mess up the men, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a fourth button (let's call it menuButton) that is used to show/hide the other three buttons. You can then add the OnClickListener to the menuButton and set the visibility of the other three buttons from `VISIBLE` to `GONE` and the other way around.

So:

```
Button menuButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
menuButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (buttonsVisible) {
            otherButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use menu or action bar, which would simplify things for you (you wouldn't have to worry about showing/hiding your buttons, etc). Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). Also, if you're on Android 3.0+, it is recommended to migrate to action bar:

> On Android 3.0 and higher, items from the options menu are presented by the action bar as a combination of on-screen action items and overflow options. Beginning with Android 3.0, the Menu button is deprecated (some devices don't have one), so you should migrate toward using the action bar to provide access to actions and other options.

Of course, some work is required, but in the end, you will have a much more flexible solution (eg. if you will later want to add another action...)